# HttpWebClient has High Memory Use in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, https, xamarin.ios, out-of-memory, ntlm

I have a MonoTouch based iOS universal app.  It uses REST services to make calls to get data.  I'm using the HttpWebRequest class to build and make my calls.  Everything works great, with the exception that it seems to be holding onto memory.  I've got usings all over the code to limit the scope of things.  I've avoided anonymous delegates as well as I had heard they can be a problem.  I have a helper class that builds up my call to my REST service.  As I make calls it seems to just hold onto memory from making my calls.  I'm curious if anyone has run into similar issues with the HttpWebClient and what to do about it.  I'm currently looking to see if I can make a call using an nsMutableRequest and just avoid the HttpWebClient, but am struggling with getting it to work with NTLM authentication.  Any advice is appreciated.

```
protected T IntegrationCall<T,I>(string methodName, I input) {
HttpWebRequest invokeRequest = BuildWebRequest<I>(GetMethodURL(methodName),"POST",input, true);
WebResponse response = invokeRequest.GetResponse();

T result = DeserializeResponseObject<T>((HttpWebResponse)response);
invokeRequest = null;
response = null;
return result;
}

protected HttpWebRequest BuildWebRequest<T>(string url, string method, T requestObject, bool IncludeCredentials)
{
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Validator;

        var invokeRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (invokeRequest == null)
            return null;

        if (IncludeCredentials)
        {
            invokeRequest.Credentials = CommonData.IntegrationCredentials;
        }

        if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(method) )
            invokeRequest.Method = method;
        else
            invokeRequest.Method = "POST";
        invokeRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
        invokeRequest.Timeout = 40000;

        using( Stream requestObjectStream = new MemoryStream() )
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializedObject = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializedObject.WriteObject(requestObjectStream, requestObject);

            requestObjectStream.Position = 0;
            using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(requestObjectStream))
            {
                string strTempRequestObject = reader.ReadToEnd();

                //byte[] requestBodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strTempRequestObject);
                Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(false);
                byte[] requestBodyBytes = enc.GetBytes(strTempRequestObject);

                invokeRequest.ContentLength = requestBodyBytes.Length;

                using (Stream postStream = invokeRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    postStream.Write(requestBodyBytes, 0, requestBodyBytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        return invokeRequest;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using memory profiler? How big are the data you're working with?

Answer (score 1):

Using **using** is the right thing to do - but your code seems to be duplicating the same content multiple times (which it should not do).

`requestObjectStream` is turned into a `string` which is then turned into a `byte[]` before being written to another stream. And that's **without** considering what the extra code (e.g. `ReadToEnd` and `UTF8Encoding.GetBytes`) might allocate themselves (e.g. like more [strings](http://www.mono-project.com/Performance_Tips#Strings), byte[]...).

So if what you serialize is large then you'll consume a lot of extra memory (for nothing). It's even a bit worse for `string`and `byte[]` since you can't dispose them manually (GC will decide when, making measurement harder).

I would try (but did not ;-) something like:

```
    ...

    using (Stream requestObjectStream = new MemoryStream ()) {
        DataContractSerializer serializedObject = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializedObject.WriteObject(requestObjectStream, requestObject);
        requestObjectStream.Position = 0;

        invokeRequest.ContentLength = requestObjectStream.Length;
        using (Stream postStream = invokeRequest.GetRequestStream())
           requestObjectStream.CopyTo (postStream);
    } 

    ...
```

That would let the `MemoryStream` copy itself to the request stream. An alternative is to call `ToArray` to the `MemoryStream` (but that's another copy of the serialized object that the GC will have to track and free).

Comment: The only strings that are normally interned are compile-time constants in code. Why do you think those large strings would get interned?

Comment: You are right, there was duplicate activity going on there I didn't need that was left over from some debugging.  I cut out the extra steps of string -> byte -> post stream.  At a minimum the code is more efficient.  However, I didn't see a drop in memory.  Have you seen any issues with the HttpWebClient, or do you think I am likely chasing the wrong thing?

Comment: @svick : good point, I went too far (wrt question) ranting on `string` :-) I edited my answer to stay on subject @Mark it's hard to say, are your serialization object large (if so then you should see some difference) ? also we do not know how (tools/technique) you're measuring your memory consumption ?

Comment: I am using Instruments to watch the total bytes used.  I don't know that it works 100% w/ MonoTouch, but it does show when memory warnings are thrown, which corresponds with when I see the app crash after making a bunch of calls for data.